# Почему не работает привязка?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

В DataContext в рантайме передается CameraViewModel, судя по отладчику он действительно там есть, но свойство CurrentFrame не привязывается, причем если пытаться привязаться, например к лейблу и туда текст какой-нибудь писать, то нормально привязывается

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfDrawing.View.CameraView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:WpfDrawing.ViewModel" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:CameraViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="cameraFrameElement" Source="{Binding CurrentFrame}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

VM:

```
public class CameraViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ImageSource currentFrame;
        public ImageSource CurrentFrame
        {
            get => currentFrame;
            set
            {
                currentFrame = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentFrame");
            }
        }
        public CameraViewModel(CameraManager cameraManager)
        {
            CameraManager = cameraManager;
            CameraManager.PropertyChanged += CameraManager_PropertyChanged;

        }

        private void CameraManager_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentFrame = CameraManager.CurrentFrame;
        }

        public CameraManager CameraManager { get; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            //if (PropertyChanged != null)
            //    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Обычно, `UserControl` привязывается иначе, ему не задают `DataContext`, у него делают свойство зависимости, к которому уже привязывают нужный контрол через имя (`<UserControl ... x:Name="uc" ...` и `{Binding Property, ElementName = uc}`), а уже затем, делают `<local:MyUserControl Property = "{Binding SomeProp}"/>`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Если можно, то поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: А чего тут еще подробней можно говорить? Контролы должны быть независимы от тех данных, что используются у вас в программе, а у вас сейчас идет строгая привязка к свойству `CurrentFrame`, которое у вас в программе может и не быть. Представьте, что контрол, это отдельный и независимый компонент, со своими органами управления, который лежит, к примеру в библиотеке, вот как поступите? Выше я вам уже сказал решение, вам остается создать свойство зависимости в C# коде контрола, делается это простым `propdp` и нажатием TAB, вам студия сгенерирует код.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно привязываться к установленным ресурсам

```
<Image Source="../Resources/ToolBar/document_back.png" />
```

Или CurrentFrame должен быть типом string в котором прописан путь к файлу изображения